# @beforeclass methods get executed in same thread if we put parallel="tests" in the suite xml

Tags: testng, parallel-testing

I have a test suite where I am using parallelism by using annotation like :

```
test name="All Regular Tests" parallel="tests" thread-count="30"
```

Now, let's say we have multiple @test annotation in one class. and it has @beforeclass annotation method as well. So when separate thread will pick the tests from same class, will it execute the @beforeclass methods in both threads or will it share the same data.

Or shall I use parallel="methods", what is the correct way ?

Not able to understand the concept of parallelism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see why you are confused.

It makes no sense to use `parallel="tests"` in the test tag.
parallel="tests" is dictating that all the  defined in the XML are run in different threads. But you are assigning that to a test level, so it will only apply that option for that test.

You have two options here.

To put the multithreading option at a suite level, with the "tests" parallelization:
`<suite name = "ParallelTesting" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">`

Or to put it on the test level, with "method" option:
`<test name = "Test Parallelism" parallel="method" thread-count="2">`

So:

- **"tests":** for each  in the XML file.
- **"method":** for each @Test method in wherever you put the property (all the @Tests in the suite, all the @Tests in a class, etc.)

Regarding yout second question, no, it will run the @BeforeClass only once. You can put it to the test very easily:

**XML File: parallel=tests on suite level:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name = "ParallelTesting" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

    <test name = "Test Parallelism 1" >
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.test.testing.test.TestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name = "Test Parallelism 2" >
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.test.testing.test.TestClass2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

**Test Class 1:**

```
public class TestClass {

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("Class 1 - Before Class with Thread Id:- "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        System.out.println("Class 1 - Test Case A with Thread Id:- " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testB() {
        System.out.println("Class 1 - Test Case B with Thread Id:- " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

}
```

**Test Class 2:**

```
public class TestClass2 {

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("Class 2 - Before Class with Thread Id:- "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        System.out.println("Class 2 - Test Case A with Thread Id:- " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testB() {
        System.out.println("Class 2 - Test Case B with Thread Id:- " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Class 1 - Before Class with Thread Id:- 12
Class 2 - Before Class with Thread Id:- 13
Class 2 - Test Case A with Thread Id:- 13
Class 1 - Test Case A with Thread Id:- 12
Class 2 - Test Case B with Thread Id:- 13
Class 1 - Test Case B with Thread Id:- 12

===============================================
ParallelTesting
Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

---

The two other variations of parallelization are (using the same classes above):

**XML File: parallel=method on suite level:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name = "ParallelTesting2" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">

    <test name = "Test Parallelism 1" >
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.test.testing.test.TestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name = "Test Parallelism 2" >
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.test.testing.test.TestClass2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

**Output:**

```
Class 1 - Before Class with Thread Id:- 12
Class 1 - Test Case B with Thread Id:- 13
Class 1 - Test Case A with Thread Id:- 12
Class 2 - Before Class with Thread Id:- 14
Class 2 - Test Case A with Thread Id:- 14
Class 2 - Test Case B with Thread Id:- 15
```

---

**XML File: parallel=method on test level:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name = "ParallelTesting2" >

    <test name = "Test Parallelism 1" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.test.testing.test.TestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name = "Test Parallelism 2" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.test.testing.test.TestClass2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

**Output:**

```
Class 1 - Before Class with Thread Id:- 12
Class 1 - Test Case A with Thread Id:- 12
Class 1 - Test Case B with Thread Id:- 13
Class 2 - Before Class with Thread Id:- 14
Class 2 - Test Case B with Thread Id:- 15
Class 2 - Test Case A with Thread Id:- 14
```

---

And finally, what I mention it wouldn't make sense to do:

**XML File: parallel=tests on test level:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name = "ParallelTesting2" >

    <test name = "Test Parallelism 1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.test.testing.test.TestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name = "Test Parallelism 2" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.test.testing.test.TestClass2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

**Output:**

```
Class 1 - Before Class with Thread Id:- 1
Class 1 - Test Case A with Thread Id:- 1
Class 1 - Test Case B with Thread Id:- 1
Class 2 - Before Class with Thread Id:- 1
Class 2 - Test Case A with Thread Id:- 1
Class 2 - Test Case B with Thread Id:- 1
```

As you can see in that last example, everything runs on the same thread because you are asking to each test (group of methods) to run tests in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and time. But can you put the output for same but put parallel="tests" and can check.

Comment: The output I put there is for parallel="tests".

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i meant for "methods". Copy-paste issue.

Comment: There I added all the examples. So there you have now the output of every combination, and the result of what happens if you ask each test to run parallelization by test. So any of the first three examples would work for you, but not the fourth. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Ohh, yeah that really helped. Thanks for your time and effort.